# How to keep logged in session after user is successfully authenticated with his iCloud Account?

Tags: javascript, icloud, cloudkit-web-services

This is what I call when my site is loaded:

```
(function($){})(window.jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {

  window.addEventListener('cloudkitloaded', function() {

    CloudKit.configure({
      containers: [{
        containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice',
        apiToken: 'fc363369412ad6c99020e7e0ed3e2be121008e34534cff7debe1f4f7f829d152',
        environment: 'production'
      }]
    });

    var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
    var privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase;

    this.gotoAuthenticatedState = function(userInfo) {

      if(userInfo.isDiscoverable) {
        //success
      } else {
        //failure
      }

      container
      .whenUserSignsOut()
      .then(this.gotoUnauthenticatedState);
    };

    this.gotoUnauthenticatedState = function(error) {
      //do something of sign out

      container
      .whenUserSignsIn()
      .then(this.gotoAuthenticatedState)
      .catch(this.gotoUnauthenticatedState);
    };

    container.setUpAuth().then(function(userInfo) {

      if(userInfo) {
          this.gotoAuthenticatedState(userInfo);
      } else {
          this.gotoUnauthenticatedState();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And when I login with success, there correct button appears:

[image]

But every time when I refresh the page this button changes:

[image]

What to do to keep session and possibility to fetch records until user manually will log out?

How to check if there exists current session (user already authenticated itself) and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Put your token inside an `apiTokenAuth` object, and add a `persist` key.

```
CloudKit.configure({
    containers: [{
        containerIdentifier: '<your container>',
        environment: 'production',

        apiTokenAuth: {
            apiToken: '<your token>',
            persist: true
        }
    }]
});
```